# GAE app not displaying in Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

I have a small Google App Engine App that I've put in an iframe on a google site and have been running for some time now.  I just noticed that the app will not display in Firefox version 23.0.1.  I downgraded to Firefox version 22 and the form is visible and working.  The form also works current versions of Chrome and Safari.  The logs on the app engine dashboard show no error messages.  If I open up the app in Firefox 23.0.1 using the link directly to the app, it works just fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might fix this or troubleshoot further?  For now I'm just telling my users to use Chrome.

Thanks, brl8

Comment: Are you embedding a not-https page into an https one?

Comment: YES!!  That was it.  I changed the embedded link to https and it is working now.  Can you change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it?  THANKS.